# How do I test persistence layer (lightweight)

Tags: java, unit-testing, persistence

we are implementing an application for JBoss 7.1.1, building with Maven.
I tried Arquillian for integration testing but for small tests on persistence layer the build-pack-deploy roundtrip is too slow. In fact, I expect the team members tying to avoid unit testing.
To get faster, I would like to implement simple JUnit-Tests. In former projects, we did this, but I don't know, what was the clue to get it run.

I am sure, many projects do this kind of leightweight testing.

Does anybody have a simple, up-to-date cheklist to setup the infrastructure (especially maven-dependencies) and a simple Test example? Where do  have to place the persistence.xml for tests and how do I configure the data base connection?

CU,
 Thomas

Answer (score 2):

You could consider creating a in-memory [HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/), [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) database and test your persistence layer against that database. To make sure the test database has an up-to-date schema, you could either use [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) (you can use that to update your real database as well) or [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/).

If you place your `persistence.xml` for testing in `src/test/resources`, it should override the version that resides in `src/main/resources`. This way you can easily make configuration changes (for example, skip connection pooling and just use the in-memory database instead of whatever database you normally use).

After your tests have ran and the JVM has shutdown, your database is thrown away automatically.